# @font-face quality issues

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I designed a website in Photoshop and was happy with the outcome so I started coding it. I'm having some trouble with the font rendering however. The font looks horrible in browsers compared to Photoshop. The font rendered smoothly in Opera right from the start however.

After some searching I also managed to make it render smoothly in Chrome and Safari. I fixed it by moving 'svg' to the top inside @font-face in my CSS.

I'm still having trouble with Firefox and Internet Explorer however. Both latest versions I believe.

**An image ([original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQlqY.png)):**
[image]
The text in blue is the problem.

**And the @font-face code:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular';
    src: url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.svg#MuseoSlab500Regular') format('svg'),
         url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The only solution I've found and tried so far is to rearrange the lines in @font-face. Which as I said solved the issue for some browsers but not Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but your font specimen looks fine in FF and IE.

Comment: Is it the anti-aliasing? I'm not sure if that's something that can be fixed in Firefox/IE at the moment. I've noticed that as well - Webkit will render it anti-aliased whereas FF/IE will render it more sharply. I believe you can get Webkit to look like FF/IE, but not the other way around (using like `-webkit-font-smoothing`). Can possibly try `text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.004)` in ff/ie to give it a bit of fuzzy

Comment: @Benno text-shadow didn't really make it look much better to be honest. I've also tried font-smooth but that didn't seem to make any difference at all (might be safari-only).

Comment: Just a thought but does adding `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` fix the problem (whateveer it is)? If so then it is an anti-alising bug in webkit.

Comment: I would, and constantly am, be more concerned about the difference in color across browsers, operating systems, monitors, etc that you're going to have (three different blues there). Bane of my existence. Wouldn't even be worried about AA unless you are dealing with LARGE fonts, in which case they are just going to look bad in some browsers. No matter the font. Web safe or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's ok for the text to be rendered slightly different across the browsers. On different OSs you'll receive even more different rendering (try to check OS X or Ubuntu). And that's ok too. Photoshop is a bad reference here, the browser provides a final look and the browser displays your website to your user.

Instead, I believe you should correct your syntax, cause it will not work for IE 8-. You are declaring `src` property with EOT font — that will work, but for IE 6+ only. Then you are redeclaring it, and since you are including more that one format, IE will fail it to load and will back up to the default font.

Additional reading you might be interested in:

- [A Closer Look At Font Rendering](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/)
- [The New Bulletproof @Font-Face
  Syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

Comment: Alright, that's too bad. The syntax has been corrected and I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why the renderings differ, and mostly you cannot do much about them. Trying to play with font formats just adds some variation to the theme – different systems still render fonts differently.

It looks like Firefox is applying kerning (e.g., “ä” is closer to the preceding “V” than on ther browsers). However, at least the Museo font available from fonts.com has no kern pairs. But you did not specify where you got the font from-

Comment: I got the font from: [Fontspring.com](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-slab)

Comment: Strangely, when I look at the font as downloaded from Fontspring.com and use Font Properties Extension to check out the TTF file, the information is that there are no kerning pairs. Yet, Firefox has applied kerning, and you can see a small difference on Firefox if you test with the CSS setting `-moz-font-feature-settings: "kern" 0` (which disables kerning, which is “on” in modern versions of Firefox by default). But according to Font Explorer X, the font has no kerning for “Vä”, yet Firefox kerns it. Maybe the WOFF file has kerning different from the TTF file (very odd).